# How can we generate wadl using enunciate

Tags: java, wadl, enunciate

I would like to generate wadl using enunciate. What configuration changes I need to do for that ?

As per http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE-688, the enunicate seems to have support for wadl generation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to make any custom configuration changes. Assuming the [XML module](http://enunciate.codehaus.org/module_xml.html) is enabled (it is enabled by default), the WADL will get generated.